# play framework - how can i call this function for the authenticated user in this code play2 scala zentasks

Tags: scala, forms-authentication, action, playframework-2.0

in the play2 scala zentasks sample application  the code snippet looks like this

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

What I need to do is call this function in model

```
def AddOnline(email: String, contact: Contact) = {
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL(
    """
      update contact
      set online_status = {'online'} //I want to write the value contact.status=online
      where email = {email}
    """
  ).on(
    'email -> contact.email,
    'online_status -> contact.online_status
  ).executeUpdate()
}
```

}

But my challenge here is to call this `AddOnline` function every time a certain user is authenticated by the above piece of code. Can someone suggest how I should go about this? I am a novice in this and I am going round and round in circles without making any progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `addOnline` method from the `IsAuthenticated` like this:

```
 def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
   Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
   // Do what you need to do here before the action is called
   Contact.addOnline(user)
   Action(request => f(user)(request))
 }
```

Please note that the `user` is not the user object but just the email of the authenticated user.

Also, as you are only adding the online status of the `user` it looks like you can simplify your AddOnline method to something like this.

```
def addOnline(email: String) = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL(
      """
        update contact
        set online_status = 'online'
        where email = {email}
      """
    ).on(
      'email -> email,
  ).executeUpdate()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesn't give me any errors on implementing it this way but somehow the online_status is not getting set in the database. It doesn't even given any error but when the display happens, the online_status doesn't seem to be updated